# Session data lost on concurrent ajax requests

Tags: laravel

Laravel 9, using redis for session storage (was using file before).

I have a controller method that puts data in the session, and then returns a view. That view uses DataTables and loads data from a different method in the same controller. If the view only has one DataTable, or if i set $.ajaxSetup to use async: false, then it works fine. But if more than 2 or 3 requests fire off at the same time the first 1 or 2 complete successfully but the rest come up blank as those variables are missing from the session. The behavior is not consistent which leads me to believe it's some sort of race condition.

Note, the ajax controller method does not modify the session, it only queries and returns json data. When the issue occurs, the user isn't logged out or anything, it just "forgets" the few session variables i had set. I found that if i take the ajax URL (hxxp://site.com/reports/ajax?key=12345) and spam refresh in the browser i can reproduce the same outcome. If i refresh slowly (once per second or so) it never exhibits the problem. The session isn't getting completely destroyed, as the user stays logged in. I also know that the bad ajax requests still retain some session data as they're making it past the guard and into the controller.

The reason for storing this data in the session is because it's short lived (less than the lifetime of the session), and it all needs to be queried and processed at the same time as the different reports cross reference each other. If i made the ajax calls query the data on request then i would be duplicating external API calls multiple times and running a lot of extra server-side processing.

What i have tried:

- I switched from file to redis sessions hoping that would help, but it
  did not.
- Attempted adding block to the route, no change.
- Tried rairlie/laravel-locking-session but it did not run properly, and
  isn't tested on redis sessions.
- Disabled CSRF verification on the ajax route just in case that was the problem.
- Added some debug to the ajax controller method to see what's in the session during the   failure condition, it's basically just the token and guard data, nothing else.

Sample code:

ReportController.php

```
class ReportController extends Controller {
  function getReport(Request $request) {
    session()->put('report1_data',$jsonData1);
    session()->put('report2_data',$jsonData2);
    session()->put('report3_data',$jsonData3);
    return view('reports');
  }

  function getAjaxData(Request $request) {
    $result=json_decode(session()->get($request->get('key')),JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
    return response()->json($result);
  }
}
```

reports.blade.php:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#table_report1').DataTable({ ajax: '{{ URL::route('reports.ajaxdata',['key'=>'report1_data']) }}';
  $('#table_report2').DataTable({ ajax: '{{ URL::route('reports.ajaxdata',['key'=>'report2_data']) }}';
  $('#table_report3').DataTable({ ajax: '{{ URL::route('reports.ajaxdata',['key'=>'report3_data']) }}';
});
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth:customer']],function() {
  Route::controller(\App\Http\Controllers\ReportController::class)->group(function(){
    Route::get('reports','getReport')->name('reports');
    Route::get('ajax','getAjaxData')->name('reports.ajaxdata');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid concurrent requests when these requests are writing into the session.

You can look at the session blocking feature of Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#session-blocking as well. It will allow you to lock the session behind some routes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's the thing that threw me on this was that i'm not writing anything to the session. The data is written in one request, and then read from in 3 different requests. However if those 3 requests operate asynchronously it doesn't work. I worked around it using cache instead of session, which is probably the better solution anyways.